# What would be the energy requirements for non FTL warp drive?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, faster-than-light, warp-drives

I have a question about Alcubierre Drive, or other Warp Drive concepts.

I have read a lot about FTL warp drive and the massive energy requirements to perform a jump, varying from bigger than the observable universe, to the size of Jupiter. 
Unfortunately, nowhere I could find the formula for the aforementioned calculation.

Assuming gravity/space manipulation is possible and achievable, I would like to know what would be the approximate energy requirements for a non-FTL warp drive. What would be a rough approximation for the required energy to lift 1 kilogram 1 meter above the ground in 1 second, though gravity/space manipulation? Or at least how different, if so, is the result compared to classical means?

From my understanding, a non-FTL gravity manipulation would still be extremely useful in transportation and space travel.

Comment: Arbitrarily low, but also you need the proper distribution of it, which may not be feasible.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can check out nasa research on that. They're focusing on micro warp effects.

[ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110015936.pdf](http://web.archive.org/web/20200121235125/https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110015936.pdf)

Even for FTL the energy requirements are extremely low. That it at first of course, not so good, because the energy conditions needed are in the negative. But with the right distribution and some sofistication one coud get even the absolute value of required energy drop down to a quite practical value.  Nonetheless one still needs negative energy which is a bit of a problem no matter how little the amount you need.

the answers probably lie in the nature of the quantum vacuum. Casimir effect is something that could be considered something producing  energy. But not necceserely in general relativistic sense.

GR is not a quantum theory anyway, so althaugh it has many exelent predictions, it is fundamentally quite flawed. So I wouldnt give too much attention to its predictions on this kind of stuff. Rather, a quantum source of gravity needs to be understood in order to have the ability to manipulate spacetime in such subtle ways.

Comment: I don’t know of any physicists who believe Sonny White, and his “research” has not to my knowledge appeared in any respectable peer-reviewed physics journals.

Comment: It's not a matter of belief, science never is. When did I say I believe the guy. I actually said I don't. Look at the answer. I said GR  is not really the model to tackle this.. But this is the only paper on this from what seemed a credible source, (NASA), If you have a problem with it take it up with them

Comment: By “believe” I meant “accept White’s research”. The fact that NASA allows this to appear on a NASA site is an embarrassment.

Comment: Maybe so. But did you research warp drive metrics? How much do you know about quantum vacuum?

Comment: I too have issues of my own with this paper, bud I think  it would be unwise not to put some serious thaugh into this. Why don't you send a better paper to nasa and educate them, or at least us here on the site, on how this could be done.

Comment: I know as much about the quantum vacuum as one learns in a course on quantum field theory at a leading university when getting a PhD. As a postdoctoral researcher I published one paper about the quantum vacuum in a particular curved spacetime, but by no means do I consider myself an expert on quantum vacua.

Comment: I have not spent any time researching warp drive metrics. My opinion of Sonny White’s work comes from Alcubierre’s own evaluation: ‘In 2012, a NASA laboratory announced that they had constructed an interferometer that they claim will detect the spatial distortions produced by the expanding and contracting spacetime of the Alcubierre metric. The work has been described in Warp Field Mechanics 101, a NASA paper by Harold Sonny White. Alcubierre has expressed skepticism about the experiment, saying: "from my understanding there is no way it can be done, probably not for centuries if at all".’

Comment: BTW, when I say “published”, I don’t mean “posted on my employer’s website”.

Comment: Given that Alcubierre *himself* thinks that Sonny White’s experiment is not credible, I see no justification for recommendIng it to Physics StackExchange readers.